# nclosure is not compatible with nodejs 0.12

Tags: node.js, google-closure

The [nclosure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nclosure) ,NodeJs Server-side Google Closure Lib, is not compatible with nodejs 0.12

compatible with nodejs 0.12

```
/node_modules/nclosure/lib/settingsloader.js:102
  if (!path || !require('path').existsSync(path)) return null;
                                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at nclosure.settingsLoader.readArgsFromJSONFile (/home/wj/work/transport/node_modules/nclosure/lib/settingsloader.js:102:33)
    at nclosure.settingsLoader.readSettingsObject (/node_modules/nclosure/lib/settingsloader.js:133:12)
    at nclosure.base.loadBaseScript_ (/node_modules/nclosure/lib/nclosurebase.js:199:53)
    at new nclosure.base (/node_modules/nclosure/lib/nclosurebase.js:69:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/nclosure/lib/nclosurebase.js:350:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

The `path` lib does not exist in nodejs 0.12 any more? how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be not `require('path')`, but `require('fs')` , because **existsSync** function is in **fs** API. You can fork this library and fix it.